# PHP script in /etc/cron.weekly

Tags: linux, cron, debian, php

I have a php script in my website folder that needs to be executed weekly.

I am on debian 6 (root).

How can I run this php script (in cli) weekly wihtout using `crontab` ?
I mean which kind of file should I copy in `/etc/cron.weekly` to run my php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an executable PHP script with a "shebang" line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// Your PHP code goes here
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x myscript.php
```

Test it:

```
$ ./myscript.php
Hello World!
```

The "shebang" (#!) tells the shell that this script is to be executed with PHP, found in `/usr/bin/php`.

Alternatively, you could write a small shell script that invokes the PHP interpreter with your PHP script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: I will use your second option :D. Which filename must I choose? cron.sh is enough?

Comment: You may choose any name you like. Using a `.sh` suffix is optional but might be useful. I would recommend that you pick a name that describes the task the script is performing, maybe including the name of your PHP project.